# Why does my IDE say .formLogin() .and() .exceptionHandling() is deprecated?

Tags: java, spring

I had to upgrade the Java spring application from 11 to 19 so most of the code had the be changed because some things were deprecated. This includes the .antMatchers() being changed to .requestMatchers(), however when I changed this is my code I was left with some strange syntax errors that say  .formLogin() .and() .exceptionHandling() is deprecated and marked for removal

```
@Deprecated(since = "6.1", forRemoval = true)
```

```
.formLogin()
 .loginPage("/login")
 .permitAll()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: There's a new fluent style that uses lambdas. See the migration guide https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration/index.html

Answer (score 6):

Like [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1898563/michael) said:

> There's a new fluent style that uses lambdas...

So, you can do this way:

```java
.formLogin(formLogin ->
    formLogin
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
)
```

Check the [*migration guide*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/migration-7/configuration.html).